# how to access MediaPlayer on ViewHolder from outside method

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

i create a MediaPlayer on Viewholder like this

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        RoundedImageView imageView;
        TextView username;
        ImageButton buttonInfo;
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
        public ViewHolder(@NonNull @NotNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemCardStackView);
            username = itemView.findViewById(R.id.textViewUsername_stackView);
            buttonInfo = itemView.findViewById(R.id.buttonToInfo_stackView);
        }

        void setData(Users data) {
             mediaPlayer  = new MediaPlayer();
            if (!data.getAudioIntro().equals("")) {
                try {

                    mediaPlayer.setDataSource(data.getAudioIntro());
                    mediaPlayer.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mp) {
                            booleanCallBack.checkAudio(true);
                            username.setText(data.getUsername());
                            Glide.with(context).load(data.getAvatar()).into(imageView);
                        }
                    });
                    mediaPlayer.prepareAsync();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }          
            imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    if (!data.getAudioIntro().equals("")) {
                        if (mediaPlayer.isPlaying())
                            mediaPlayer.pause();
                        else {
                            mediaPlayer.start();
                        }
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(context, "No Voice intro", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

but i want to stop it when CardView on Activity swiped. So i create a method can call from activity

```
 public void stopMediaplayer() {
         //I don't have idea to get MediaPlayer on ViewHolder
    }
```

when i use i just call it on Activity

```
 @Override
            public void onCardSwiped(Direction direction) {
                adapter.stopMediaplayer();                
            }
```

but i don't have idea access MediaPlayer outside. Can anyone help me? please!

**have a nice day, everyone!**

Answer (score 1):

Move ViewHolder class to adaptor class. so it's now an Inner Class. then MediaPlayer must be in the adaptor class. so move it there.

```
public class Adapter extends BaseAdapter {
MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;

public MediaPlayer getMediaPlayer(){
  return mediaPlayer
}

  public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
      void setData(Users data) {
         mediaPlayer  = new MediaPlayer();
      }
  }     
}
```

Now you can use `mediaPlayer` in the adapter so there is access out of the adapter.

Comment: i tried it before, but when i call MediaPlayer in the adapter. when i swiped it start old music, not update music. i put it in Viewholder then i work perfectly, i don't know why?

Answer (score 0):

make it static like this so it will be available in every class

```
  public static  MediaPlayer mediaPlayer;
```

Comment: the problem's i can't init it on Adapter.

Comment: you can create it activity and init where you want